# Single-scroll webpage with sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I place the page content of the following example - http://jsfiddle.net/cq8dC/ to the right side of the `nav` sidebar, rather than behind it?

Comment: Put some code in your question please. A link to jsFiddle is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the style. Add style `padding-left: 255px;` to **.horizontal**

```
.horizontal 
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 255px;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cq8dC/4/)**

Comment: Try and scroll horizontally. Maybe using `margin-left` is a better idea

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working in FF or Chrome. When you click the buttons the content is still being overridden.

Comment: As I said, It's still being overridden when you scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/cq8dC/6/)

First, you should add a container to your content. I've called it `#Content`.

Then I've added these stylings to the CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Content {
    left: 240px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This makes the #Content take the resting place in the page and be scrollable on its own.

---

Also I've updated the **JavaScript**

The root is now the #Content element and I'm using [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) instead of [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). I'm doing this because **position()** `Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent` (from the documentation).

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. The content moved to right of sidebar. But the links are not working now. See my answer please. I believe it is the right way to do it.